# Files io threads vs shuffle io threads

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Can someone explain the difference between
Files io threads and shuffle io threads, as I couldn't find any explanation.
I'm specifically asking about these:

```
spark.rpc.io.serverThreads
spark.rpc.io.clientThreads
spark.rpc.io.threads

spark.files.io.serverThreads
spark.files.io.clientThreads
spark.files.io.threads
```